# is ESlint integrated validation for ES6 sufficient?

Tags: eslint

Do i need a style guide as eslint-rules-es2015 to define rules with ES6 in ESLint ?
With a basic config, i already get some validations :

```
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true
  }
}
```

What is the best practice at the time ?

Answer (score 0):

ESLint has all rules turned off by default. Setting `env` to ES6 will enable ES6 global variables and will let parser know to parse your code as ES6, but it will not do anything else. You either need to specify which rules you want to turn on in `rules` section of the config, or extend an existing config (for example `eslint:recommended` or [`AirBnB`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb) or some other.)

With the config you posted above, the only errors you will see will be parser errors, when your javascript is invalid and can't be parsed.